# VLC compile on mac can't find MacOSX.sdk

Tags: macos, vlc

Following the VLC macOSCompile wiki page. Using the single command build instructions. I'm running 10.14.6 with Xcode 11.3.1 commandline tools, developer signed, etc.

Important note -- my MacOSX.sdk file is located here:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk

All is good through build to create makefile, completes bootstrap and runs make. Then I get the following error -- how do I point VLC to the location where my MacOSX.sdk file is located?

IOW how do I set vlc's "contrib environment"?

Please note in the code snip below, that contrib sets the MacOSX.sdk file pointer to the WRONG location - how do I fix?

Do I need to edit something in the vlc source? Thanks. errors:

```
Setting base environment
Using VLC root dir /Users/GR99/temp/VLC/vlc and triplet x86_64-apple-darwin18
[build] Checking for python3 ...
Python 3.8.1
[build] Building in "/Users/GR99/temp/VLC/vlc/build"
[build] Building building tools
You are ready to build VLC and its contribs
Setting symbol environment
Setting contrib environment with minimum macOS version 10.11 and SDK /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
[build] Building contribs
Packages licensing...    GPL version 3
Creating makefile...
Bootstrap completed.
Run "make" to start compilation.

....

make: Nothing to be done for `fetch'.
make: `.gettext' is up to date.
# Framework
cd breakpad/src/client/mac/ && xcodebuild MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11 -sdk /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk WARNING_CFLAGS=-Werror=partial-availability OTHER_CFLAGS=-fno-stack-check -arch x86_64 CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY=libc++
# Build Sparkle and change the @rpath
cd sparkle && xcodebuild MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11 -sdk /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk WARNING_CFLAGS=-Werror=partial-availability OTHER_CFLAGS=-fno-stack-check -arch x86_64
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk" cannot be located.
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk" cannot be located.
make: *** [.sparkle] Error 64
make: *** [.breakpad] Error 64
make: Target `all' not remade because of errors.
# Framework
cd breakpad/src/client/mac/ && xcodebuild MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.11 -sdk /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk WARNING_CFLAGS=-Werror=partial-availability OTHER_CFLAGS=-fno-stack-check -arch x86_64 CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY=libc++
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk" cannot be located.
make: *** [.breakpad] Error 64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cf: `../extras/package/macosx/build.sh -h`

It says:

```
usage: extras/package/macosx/build.sh [options]

Build vlc in the current directory

OPTIONS:
   -h            Show some help
   -q            Be quiet
   -j            Force number of cores to be used
   -r            Rebuild everything (tools, contribs, vlc)
   -c            Recompile contribs from sources
   -p            Build packages for all artifacts
   -i <n|u>      Create an installable package (n: nightly, u: unsigned stripped release archive)
   -k <sdk>      Use the specified sdk (default: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk)
   -a <arch>     Use the specified arch (default: x86_64)
   -C            Use the specified VLC build dir
   -b <url>      Enable breakpad support and send crash reports to this URL
   -d            Disable debug mode (on by default)
```

Your build command should also include the location of your SDK using the `-k` option:

`../extras/package/macosx/build.sh -c -k /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk`

The [script](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/103f456658ab45cda7908b81c0b91815fe2cc031/extras/package/macosx/build.sh#L14) uses `xcrun --show-sdk-path` to set the SDK otherwise.  `xcrun` uses the environment variable $SDKROOT.

Note: You might want to install and use the versioned SDK, for example in your question the output shows that it is targeting minimum *El Capitan*, `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk`
The versioned SDKs are available in old Xcodes, and on [github](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases/download/10.15/MacOSX10.11.sdk.tar.xz).

Setting up the "contrib environment" is all handled by the "single command".

Comment: THANK YOU! I have MacOSX10.15.sdk and can point to that -- thank you so very much.

Comment: Sure.  You will be able to target macos 10.15+ with that SDK.